# Rails calculate averages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a rake task in which I am calculating the average for a set of products, however I am having trouble calculating and updating the attributes for **individual** each set. What I have so far:

```
task :calculate_rating => :environment do 
total_rating = []
  Product.find(:all, :joins => :rating_sets, :conditions => ["rating_set_id = ?", 45 ]).each do |product|
  Rating.find(:all, :conditions => ["rating_set = ? and product_id =?", 45 ,product.id]).each do |ratings|
    total_rating << ratings.rating
        end
      average = total_rating.inject(:+).to_f / total_rating.size
      q = ProductRatingSet.find_by_product_id_and_rating_set_id(@product_id, 45)
      q.update_attribute(:product_rating, average)
        end
      end
```

Im trying to basically find the average and update the `product_rating` for each set that is retrieved by `Rating.find(:all, :conditions => ["rating_set = ? and product_id =?", 45 ,product.id])`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put initialization of total_rating array within your first loop

```
Product.find(:all, :joins => :rating_sets, :conditions => ["rating_set_id = ?", 45 ]).each do |product|
  total_rating = []
  Rating.find(:all, :conditions => ["rating_set = ? and product_id =?", 45 ,product.id]).each do |ratings|
    total_rating << ratings.rating
  end
  average = total_rating.inject(:+).to_f / total_rating.size
  q = ProductRatingSet.find_by_product_id_and_rating_set_id(@product_id, 45)
  q.update_attribute(:product_rating, average)
end
```

Comment: This still seems as though total_rating is being treated as a single array of values.